# Excluding a top-level directory from a setuptools package

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm trying to put a Python project into a tarball using setuptools.  The problem is that setuptools doesn't appear to like the way that the source tree was originally setup (not by me, I must add).  Everything that I actually want to distribute is in the top-level directory, rather than in a subdirectory like the setuptools docs talk about.

The tree has a directory, `tests`, that I don't want to have in the released package.  However, using `exclude_package_data` doesn't seem to actually do any excluding, and I'd like to work out what I've done wrong.

My `setup.py` looks like this, in relevant part:

```
setup(
  name="project",
  packages=[''],
  include_package_data=True,
  exclude_package_data={'': ['tests']},
  test_suite='nose.collector',
)
```

Comment: Note that the [content of the source distribution](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/#how-files-are-included-in-an-sdist) (e.g. `dist/*.tar.gz`) is not the same as that of the [built distribution](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/#term-Built-Distribution) (e.g. `dist/*.whl`). So your `tar.gz` may contain `tests`, whereas your `whl` does not. To be sure, you could also try `pip install <path to your tar.gz>` in a fresh venv and check what ends up in the site-packages folder.

Answer (score 60):

I have wasted several hours on the same problem, trying to exclude a module, I finally found that I had to remove the `*.egg-info` and `build` directories, that somehow retained the idea that the module had to be included.

Comment: Oh my... Thank you! Hours wasted here too.

Comment: Again, many, MANY thanks! I wasted all morning trying to fix this idea.  This entire packaging and install if WAY over complicated and WAY too buggy. Just look at all the problems. But getting it fixed might require a tremendous effort in designing an entirely new system so we don't have to drag all this backward compatibility nonsense. YUCK!

Comment: In my case, removing only the `*.egg-info` directory was sufficient.

Comment: Wasted two hours on this, thanks so much for clarifying!!

Comment: Removing the `egg-info` directory did it, god I was already on track to wasting another evening!

Comment: Ditto, many thanks!! This is entirely not documented, from what I can tell.

Comment: WTF. That might explain why so many answers about building packages appear broken or as if they are doing strictly nothing. They might actually be working. You just don't see the results without first removing egg-info folder. Sigh..

Comment: I spent two hours trying everything before I came across your answer. Thank you very much for your helpful response.

Answer (score 35):

We use the following convention to exclude 'tests' from packages.

```
setup(
   name="project",
   packages=find_packages(exclude=("tests",)),
   include_package_data=True, 
   test_suite='nose.collector',
)
```

We also use MANIFEST.in to better control what `include_package_data=True` does.

Comment: Oddly enough, using `exclude=()` was not enough for me. Per http://stackoverflow.com/a/11669299/472876 , I had to use `recursive-exclude tests *` in my `MANIFEST.in` for success.

Comment: @HeyWatchThis Did your `tests/` directory have a `__init__.py` file in it? Maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: Don't forget to clean-up your `build`, `dist` and `*.egg-info` directories.

Comment: @code_dredd: if it was a regular folder and not a Python package you woudn't have to exclude it from finding PACKAGES in the first place. BTW, I have the same issue as HeyWatchThis. Python and it's stunted and misshapen distribution process...

Answer (score 21):

This is what I found in [setuptools manual](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#using-find-packages):

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
...
packages = find_packages(exclude=["*.tests", "*.tests.*", "tests.*", "tests"]),
```

In my case the following was enough to exclude top-level tests directory:

```
packages = find_packages(exclude=["tests.*", "tests"]),
```

Answer (score 13):

I have the following in my `setup.py`...

```
setup(name='pyfoo',
      version="1.0.2",
      description='Example for stack overflow',
      url='http://stackoverflow.com/',
      author='David Michael Pennington',
      author_email='mike /|at|\ pennington.net',
      license='GPL',
      platforms='any',
      keywords='Stack Overflow Example',
      entry_points = "",
      long_description=read('README.rst'),
      include_package_data=True,  # Checks MANIFEST.in for explicit rules
      #                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      packages=find_packages(),
      use_2to3=True,
      zip_safe=False,
      setup_requires=["setuptools_hg"],
```

I had a `doc/` directory that was getting massive due to the number of images I had in it; this meant that the size of my `sdist` was growing over 500kB.  Originally I had this in my `MANIFEST.in`...

```
include LICENSE CHANGES README.rst requirements.txt
recursive-exclude * __pycache__
recursive-exclude * *.pyc
recursive-exclude * *.pyo
recursive-exclude * *.orig
```

The only thing I had to do to exclude my doc directory was this line at the bottom of `MANIFEST.in`...

```
prune doc*
```

Using `prune doc*` suddenly removed all my `doc/` directory from the `sdist` tarball.  So, it looks like you just need to use this in a `MANIFEST.in` file...

```
prune tests*
```

Answer (score 7):

Ug, setuptools makes this really tricky :(

I don't know if this is what you want, but one project I work on uses a combination of two things:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
...
packages = find_packages(exclude=['tests']),
data_files = os.walk(path_to_files),
```

Answer (score 5):

An additional solution that worked in my case.
Apparently:
packages=setuptools.find_packages(exclude=["tests.*", "tests"]),

didn't work, but:

```
packages=setuptools.find_packages(exclude=["*tests.*", "*tests"]),
```

adding the star character at the beginning of the word did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For similar purpose, my collegue wrote setuptools-dummy package: http://github.com/ella/setuptools-dummy/tree/master

Take a look at setuptools_dummy, modify excludes to your needs and it should work. If not, open an issue ;)