# setuptools troubles -- excluding packages, including data files

Tags: python, configuration, setuptools

I'm fairly new to setuptools. I've seen a few similar questions and it drives a little bit insane that I've seemed to follow advice I saw but setuptools still does something different than what I want.

Here is the structure of my project:

```
.
..
package1/
    __init__.py
    abc.py
    ...
tests/
    __init__.py
    test_package1.py
LICENSE
README.md
RELEASE
setup.py
```

And here is the contents of my setup.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
#from distutils.core import setup
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='package1',
    version='1.1',
    test_suite="tests",
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests']),    
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data = {
        '': ['LICENSE', 'README.md5', 'RELEASE']
    },   
)
```

Also, in my manifest file I have:

```
include LICENSE
include RELEASE
include README.md
```

I build the tar with:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

I want to:

1. Exclude `tests` directory from the source distribution;
2. Have LICENSE, README.md, RELEASE files in the site-packages directory, either at the top level, or inside the package1 directory (at this point I will agree to either).

Instead, here's what happens:

1. `tests` directory remains to be in the created tar archive and gets installed to the site-packages;
2. Files are copied to the archive, but do not get installed to the site-packaged directory of the package.

I am out of ideas, can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: why python doesn't love us... It is a very simple and common task: _ignore several files, and include several uncommon files to package_. Why is it so hard to do?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should create a new file called `MANIFEST.in` in the root level of your package, then follow these instructions:

1. To control which files end up in your tar file, create a new file called `MANIFEST.in` in the root level of your package. For example, you can exclude whole directories from your distribution, using `recursive-exclude` in the `MANIFEST.in` file. In your case, you need your `MANIFEST.in` file to contain:

   ```
   recursive-exclude tests *
   ```
2. It's not common to include README and other files in the site-packages directory, but if you really want to, then go inside `package1` and create symbolic links to the files you want to include:

   ```
   cd package1
   ln -s ../LICENSE
   ln -s ../README.md
   ln -s ../RELEASE
   ```

   Then change the following line in your setup.py:

   ```
   package_data = {
       '': ['LICENSE', 'README.md', 'RELEASE']
   ```

   to:

   ```
   package_data = {
       'package1': ['LICENSE', 'README.md', 'RELEASE']
   ```

Answer (score 28):

`find_packages` uses `fnmatchcase` for its exclude filtering.  You can test if your exclusion pattern  matches a package name as follows:

```
>>> from fnmatch import fnmatchcase
>>> fnmatchcase('my.package.name.tests', 'tests')
False
```

Assuming all the tests in your project live in package names ending in `tests` or subpackages of those packages, the following should suffice to exclude all the test code:

```
setup(
    name='package1',
    version='1.1',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests', '*.tests', '*.tests.*']),    
)
```

To also exclude the `tests` folder from source distributions, add the following to MANIFEST.in:

```
recursive-exclude tests *
```

Comment: I've struggled a lot with the syntax for `find_packages()` and a useful trick I've found is to `import setuptools` in a python console in the folder where your `setup.py` resides; and then do things like this to see what packages it will list in response to the file-matching patterns you choose: `print(setuptools.find_packages(where='YourSourceFolder', exclude=['tests', 'tests.*']))`

Comment: If all the tests live in a subpackage, i.e. in a subdirectory under the main package directory, then it is apparently sufficient to specify `packages=find_packages(exclude=['*.tests', '*.tests.*']),` , and no `MANIFEST.in` file entry is needed. At least this is what my experiment under Python 3.7 told me.

Answer (score 6):

I was trying everything and nothing seemed to work, until I deleted the `build` directory (after seeing [another answer mentioning `*.egg-info/` directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48912748/2705757)) and it finally worked. `python setup.py clean --all` should also do the job.

Comment: Thank you, this was the cause of the issues I was having. The setup.py clean --all did not work and clean everything for me.

Answer (score 0):

if your structure is true:

1. the tests folder is not a package (it doesn't have the **init**.py file), so find_package don't exclude it.
2. include_package_data=True mean that all versionned files will be included if not explicitly excluded .

so : try an exclude tests/* in your MANIFEST.in

I Hope it had helped

Comment: I do have __init__.py in tests, actually, just did not show it in the source. In fact, if I print find_packages() result, it does only return package1. But the tests folder is still included.

Answer (score 0):

MANIFEST.in would take care of it.

```
prune tests/
include LICENSE  README.md RELEASE
```

if you have static files to be added, add them with

```
...
recursive-include package1/static *
```