# Why find_packages(exclude=xxx) does not work when doing setup.py sdist?

Tags: python, setup.py

I am packaging my source code, but I do not want to include tests and docs because it will be too big.

To do that I include in my setup.py:

```
setup(...
      packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests.*','tests','docs.*','docs']),
      ...
)
```

When doing a

```
python setup.py sdist
```

I can see that my root tests/ and docs/ dirs and everything inside are still included in the generated distribution.

It seems that only

```
python setup.py bdist
```

is sensible to the exclude parameter.

Why ? is it possible to exclude dirs for 'setup.py sdist' ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing the *.egg-info/ directory : it seems that this directory memorized some older settings...

Comment: This is quite odd. Your answer solved the issue for me and I had to run in circles for quite a while trying all different kind of solutions

Comment: very helpful. please make this as the answer. thanks!

Comment: For people who intend to exclude packages recursively, they also need to exclude the wildcard variation.

Comment: For anyone that finds this: I had to remove *.egg-info as well as the contents of the build/ directory after adding `recursive-exclude tests *` to the MANIFEST.in file and `["tests", "tests.*"]` to exclude.

Comment: For me, it was the same but I needed to remove the `build` folder.

Comment: Great, this helpful!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but I was being dumb and misusing the `exclude` parameter.

If you have

```
packages=setuptools.find_packages(exclude="tests")
```

You will be excluding the directories `"t", "e", "s", "t", "s"`

What you should have is this:

```
packages=setuptools.find_packages(exclude=["tests"])
```