# Trouble including sub-directory files in site-packages

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a development package set up like the following:

```
\polygonselector
    \polygonselector
        __init__.py
        \notebooks
            PolygonSelector.ipynb
    .gitignore
    LICENSE
    MANIFEST.in
    README.md
    setup.py
```

I am attempting to closely follow [these instructions](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html#) and the information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612733/including-non-python-files-with-setup-py) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556996/setuptools-troubles-excluding-packages-including-data-files) in order to include a Jupyter notebook (inside the `notebooks` directory) file as part of a python package. However, I haven't been able to succeed.

The MANIFEST.in file looks like this:

```
recursive-include  notebooks *
```

I also have the `include_package_data=True` line in my `setup.py` file.

Here is the [repository link](https://github.com/Ricyteach/polygonselector); I've already made a dozen commits trying to get this to work, including trying to have the `notebooks` directory at the top of the directory structure.

But no matter what I do, when I pip install from the repository, the `notebooks` directory is not included in the `Lib\site-packages directory`.

Comment: add this in manifest file `recursive-include  polygonselector/notebooks/* ` start from the directory level same as manifest.in

Comment: @pashantrana I believe that structure has already been tried as one of the previous commits. I'll try it later though.

Comment: Do you want subdirectory `notebooks` installed in `Lib\site-packages` or in `Lib\site-packages\polygonselector`?

Comment: @phd I'd like to know how to accomplish both but I think I'd prefer it to be under `polygonselector` for this project

Comment: @prashantrana the line you provided doesn't seem to work, however this does...: `polygonselector/notebooks *` but i don't really understand the difference.

Comment: @RickTeachey you can try `recursive-include polygonselector/notebooks/*.*` instead of `recursive-include polygonselector/notebooks/*`

Comment: @prashantrana ah ha, i did NOT try that one yet and i bet you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want subdirectory `notebooks` installed in `Lib\site-packages`:

Change `MANIFEST.in`:

```
recursive-include notebooks *
```

Change `setup.py`:

```
# include_package_data=True,
package_data={'polygonselector': ['../notebooks/*']},
```

To install into `Lib\site-packages\polygonselector`:

```
git mv notebooks polygonselector
```

Change `MANIFEST.in`:

```
recursive-include polygonselector/notebooks *
```

`setup.py` for this case is ok.

Comment: excellent. can you explain or point to a link discussing the difference between `polygonselector/notebooks *` and `polygonselector/notebooks/*` in MANIFEST.in?

Comment: I don't know one. And I don't think syntax `polygonselector/notebooks/*` is valid. The syntax is [`recursive-include directory patterns`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/commandref.html#sdist-cmd).