# setup.py sdist exclude packages in subdirectory

Tags: python, setuptools

I have the following project structure I would like to package:

```
├── doc
│   └── source
├── src
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── config
│   │   │   └── log.tmpl
│   │   └── job
│   ├── scripts
│   └── test
└── tools
```

I would like to package `core` under `src` but exclude `test`. Here is what I tried unsuccessfully:

```
      setup(name='core',
      version=version,  
      package_dir = {'': 'src'}, # Our packages live under src but src is not a package itself
      packages = find_packages("src", exclude=["test"]), # I also tried exclude=["src/test"]
      install_requires=['xmltodict==0.9.0',
                        'pymongo==2.7.2',
                        'ftputil==3.1',
                        'psutil==2.1.1',
                        'suds==0.4',
                        ],
      include_package_data=True,
      )
```

I know I can exclude `test` using the MANIFEST.in file, but I would be happy if you could show me how to do this with `setup` and `find_packages`.

#### Update:

After some more playing around, I realized that building the package with `python setup.py install` does what I expected (that is, it excludes `test`). However, issuing `python setup.py sdist` causes everything to be included (that is, it ignores my exclude directive). I don't know whether it is a bug or a feature, but there is still the possibility of excluding files in `sdist` using `MANIFEST.in`.

Comment: is `test` a Python package or just a directory with top-level python scripts?

Comment: it is a python package (e.g. it has an `__init__.py` file in it).

Comment: Analysis the mothod `setuptools.find_packages` in python console, we can find the mothod returns collected base packages and their child packages. `exclude='test'` exactly remove the top package, but the method will return the child package of `test` also. The correct value maybe `exclude=['test', 'test.*']`

Comment: Same issue here, setuptools.find_packages doesn't exclude the packages I wanted, but MANIFEST.in.helps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608855/excluding-a-top-level-directory-from-a-setuptools-package#comment39374906_9769754

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`find_packages("src", exclude=["test"])` works.
**The trick is to remove stale files such as `core.egg-info` directory.** In your case you need to remove `src/core.egg-info`.

Here's `setup.py` I've used:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='core',
      version='0.1',
      package_dir={'':'src'},
      packages=find_packages("src", exclude=["test"]), # <- test is excluded
      ####packages=find_packages("src"), # <- test is included
      author='J.R. Hacker',
      author_email='jr@example.com',
      url='http://stackoverflow.com/q/26545668/4279',
      package_data={'core': ['config/*.tmpl']},
)
```

To create distributives, run:

```
$ python setup.py sdist bdist bdist_wheel
```

To enable the latter command, run: `pip install wheel`.

I've inspected created files. They do not contain `test` but contain `core/__init__.py`, `core/config/log.tmpl` files.

Comment: The trick really works. I took the liberty to emphasize this in your answer. This is really a bug, that this stale file is not being re-created every time.

Comment: @Oz123: you could try to [submit the bug report at setuptools mercurial repository](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issues). There is [related (but different) issue about `clean --all`](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/issue/112/clean-all-should-delete-autogenerated-egg).

Comment: @Oz123, I think you mean that the bug is that the stale file IS being re-created every time, right?

Comment: @Alan, no, that is why I called it "stale".

Comment: Is this still a bug in 2017?! I'm having this problem with setuptools 35.0.2! I've worked-around by modifying my `setup.py` script to remove the `<package-name>.egg-info/` folder, but I'm surprised this hasn't been resolved. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @farenorth: I've tried it with setuptools 36.0.1 and you still have to artifacts created with the previous `setup.py` version -- it is a common occurence in practice in general -- some errors just disappear with a clean build.

Comment: @Oz123: the answer works without wildcards. If you think bh4r4th's answer (with wildcards) is better suited for your question, you could change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

In your `MANIFEST.in` at project root, add

```
prune src/test/
```

then build package with `python setup.py sdist`

Answer (score 1):

I probably just use wild cards as defined in the [find_packages](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) documentation. `*test*` or `*tests*` is something I tend to use as we save only test filenames with the word `test`. Simple and easy ^-^.

```
setup(name='core',
  version=version,  
  package_dir = {'': 'src'}, # Our packages live under src but src is not a package itself
  packages = find_packages("src", exclude=['*tests*']), # I just use wild card. Works perfect ^-^
  install_requires=['xmltodict==0.9.0',
                    'pymongo==2.7.2',
                    'ftputil==3.1',
                    'psutil==2.1.1',
                    'suds==0.4',
                    ],
  include_package_data=True,
  )
```

**FYI:**

I would also recommend adding following into `.gitignore`.

```
build
dist
pybueno.egg-info
```

And move build and pushing package to pypi or your private repository bit into CI/CD to make whole setup look clean and neat.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your folder is called *tests* and not *test*, it should work with the following code:

```
  setup(name='core',
  version=version,  
  package_dir = {'': 'src'}, # Our packages live under src but src is not a package itself
  packages = find_packages('src', exclude=['tests'])
  install_requires=['xmltodict==0.9.0',
                    'pymongo==2.7.2',
                    'ftputil==3.1',
                    'psutil==2.1.1',
                    'suds==0.4',
                    ],
  include_package_data=True,
  )
```

Comment: This does not work. Either test or tests directories are included in my sources

Comment: Like ssalentin, I was confused by the inconsistent use of "test" and "tests" in your example, @Oz123 (and submitted an edit in which "test" was used consistently throughout). Your comment also puzzles me. Do you mean that your source might include a directory named either "test" or "tests" and you want to capture both possibilities? Or do you mean that regardless of whether you specified "test" or "tests" in your exclude parameter, the directories were included? If you wanted to capture multiple possibilities, you would need to use a wildcard.