# Difference between `include a b.txt` and `include a/b.txt` in `MANIFEST.in` for package distribution?

Tags: python, package, manifest, setuptools

I've taken a look at [How to include docs directory in python distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63477061/whats-the-right-syntax-for-controlling-inclusion-and-exclusion-of-data-director) which shows the following examples:

```
include docs/*
recursive-include docs *
```

But then looking at [Including files in source distributions with MANIFEST.in](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/) I see:

```
include pat1 pat2 ...
```

My understanding so far is given this directory structure:

```
a/
  b.txt # File 1
b.txt # File 2
```

- `include a/b.txt` results in only file 1 being included.
- `include a b.txt` results in both file 1 file 2 being included (because all of `a` is included).

Is this right?

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be `include a/* b.txt`? You need to use _glob-style patterns_. Or if you prefer for files similar to _File 1_ use: `recursive-include a *.txt`.

Comment: @sinoroc would `include a/* *.txt` achieve same thing as `recursive-include a *.txt`? Not sure when to put the `*` after `a/` or before `.txt`.

Comment: No, it's not the same thing. You should get familiar with _glob-style patterns_. As far as I understood, `recursive-include a *.txt` would include all files whose name end with `.txt` in the directory `a` and all its subdirectories.

Comment: And `include a/* *.txt` would **1** (a/*) include all files (no matter the name) from the directory `a` (not in the sub-directories), and **2** (*.txt) all files from the current directory (not the sub-directories) whose name end with `.txt`.