# Python packaging: exclude directory from bdist_wheel

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

I have the following project structure:

```
.
├── docs
├── examples
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.rst
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── myproject
```

I want to bundle my project into a wheel. For this, I use the following `setup.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='myproject',
      version='1.0',
      description='Great project'
      long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
      author='Myself'
      packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests','test','examples'])
     )
```

When running `python setup.py bdist_wheel`, the `examples` directory is included in the wheel. How do I prevent this?

According to

[Excluding a top-level directory from a setuptools package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608855/excluding-a-top-level-directory-from-a-setuptools-package)

I would expect that `examples` is excluded.

Comment: Try to add `examples/` to `.gitignore`. And maybe you then should add `setup(..., include_package_data=True, ...)`.

Comment: I do not want to exclude examples/ from the repository. Also, why should I include_package_data? is that related to my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by using a suffixed star, `examples*`, i.e.:

```
find_packages(exclude=['*tests','examples*'])
```

(Note that I am writing `'*tests'` with a leading star,because I have test packages within each code package, as in  `myproject.mypackage.tests`. Somehow the suffixed star seems to not be necessary if there is already a prefixed one)