# Why can't I exclude `tests` directory from my python wheel using `exclude`?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-wheel

Consider the following package structure:

[image]

With the following `setup.py` contents:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='dfl_client',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['*tests*']),
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={"": ['py.typed', '*.pyi']},
)
```

When I package it using `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`, the resulting wheel:

- contains the `py.typed` file, which is good
- contains the `tests` folder, while it should be excluded according to [the `find_packages` doc](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages).

I spent hours trying to understand why with no success. Especially because it seems to work for other projects !

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/608855

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*(I spent so many time trying to understand this stupid issue that I answer my own question hoping that can save time to others facing the same problem)*

I finally found the culprit: it is a hidden interaction between `setuptools_scm` and the `include_package_data=True` flag.

By itself, `include_package_data=True` does not make the `tests` directory be included in the wheel. However if `setuptools_scm` is installed and the folder is under version control (and the `tests` directory is in the list of git-managed files), then the `exclude` directive does not seem to be taken into account anymore.

So the solution was simply to remove the `include_package_data=True`, that is actually not needed when `package_data` is present:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='dfl_client',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['*tests*']),
    package_data={"": ['py.typed', '*.pyi']},
)
```

See [setuptools doc on including files](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#including-data-files) (that is actually very straightforward about `include_package_data`) and [this related issue and workaround](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools_scm/issues/190#issuecomment-351181286) (the workaround seems to work for the wheel too, not only the sdist).

Comment: Thanks! After spending a few hours looking into the same problem I finally found this answer.