# setuptools not properly excluding tests

Tags: python, setuptools

My package structure is

```
package
   |-setup.py
   |-package
   |   |-__init__.py
   |   |-source.py
   |-test
       |-__init__.py
       |-test_source.py
```

I've got the line `packages=find_packages(exclude=['test'])` in my call to `setup()` in my package's `setup.py`.

If I `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`, then navigate in to `dist/` and unzip the `.tar.gz`, I can see the `test` directory is in the distribution.

I *specifically* told setup not to do this. Why is that there? I can't figure out how to make it stop.

Comment: try with `include` instead. i.e. `packages = find_packages(include=['pkg', f'pkg.*'])`

Comment: @rv.kvetch I don't think that's the issue. If I print the result of `find_packages()` I see `['package','test']`, and if I instead print the result of `find_packages(exclude=['test'])`, I get back `['package']`. So `setup()` is being properly fed the correct list which excludes the `test` directory. Somehow it still ends up in the distro, though.

Comment: `MANIFEST.in` ?

Comment: I'm not using a MANIFEST.in file. That shouldn't be necessary. I do happen to be using the `data_files` to include a few extra things in the distro, but none of that mentions anything having to do with the `test` subpackage.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/608855, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61274967

Comment: The tests may be *included* in the source distribution (`*.tar.gz`), as mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72821651), but *excluded* from the built distribution (`*.whl`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Test files are included by default](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/#how-files-are-included-in-an-sdist):

> The following files are included in a source distribution by default:
>
> - ⋮
> - all files matching the pattern `test/test*.py`

You can use a MANIFEST.in with [`prune test`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/#manifest-in-commands).

Comment: Even if they're specifically excluded, the default overrides me? That's poor design.

Thank you, though. This explains the behavior.

Comment: @PavelKomarov: You specifically excluded it from package discovery, but it’s not being included as a package.

Comment: Yes, true. Still think it shouldn't work that way. It's confusing.