# pyproject.toml package flat layout?

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I don't want to store my single package in `src` folder for many reasons so I used to choose flat layout project structure (package folder located in project root). There is one module called `foo` and I want to discover only this one using `pyproject.toml`. I'm using latest `setuptools==65.5.0` and `Cpython 3.11`. So how can I implement flat layout package discovery with this setup?

Here is `pyproject.toml`

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools >= 65.5.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "foo"
authors = [
    #TODO add authors
]
description = "desc"
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.11"
keywords = ["keywords"]
license = {text = "MIT"}
classifiers = [
    #TODO add classifiers
]
dependencies = [
    # some deps
]

[project.optional-dependencies]
dev = [
    #TODO add optional dependencies
]

[project.gui-scripts]
foo = "foo:launch"
```

And `PROJECT_ROOT/foo/__init__.py`

```py
import sys

from .app import App

app = None

def launch(argv: list[str] = []):
    app = App(argv)
    return app.exec()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    launch(sys.argv)
```

Comment: First show your code, tell us what the issue is, and then and only then we can help you fix your issue. You are not showing anything, so there is nothing for us to help you with. -- Read this: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#flat-layout

Comment: @sinoroc added code you asked, i've seen these docs already but there is no any example of implementing this

Comment: So what is the question? What is not working? What is blocking you? -- This seems correct to me so far. -- In your question you say `foo` is a module, but for me it is a package.

Comment: @sinoroc I described my question clear enough. How can I tell setuptools that I have one package in subdir `foo`.

Comment: As far as I know *setuptools* for such a project structure will find and package the `foo` package automatically. Isn't it working for you?

Comment: @sinoroc I don't want to push my luck. I just want to explicitly declare where is my package located.

Comment: It is in the documentation: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#custom-discovery -- Give it a try, then ask again if you encounter an issue.

Comment: I guess you need a `[tool.setuptools.packages.find]` section. Skip the `where` field, I guess `namespace` is `False` by default but I am not sure so you can also set `namespace = False` explicitly, then add something like: `include = ['foo*']`. It should be good enough.

Comment: @synoroc thx, it works perfectly. You can write answer with it now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608855/excluding-a-top-level-directory-from-a-setuptools-package#comment39374906_9769754

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, *setuptools* will automatically find and package the `foo` package with the project directory as shown in your question. If you want to skip the automatic behavior and want to be explicit about it, then I think you need to add the following section to your `pyproject.toml` file:

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
include = ["foo*"]
namespaces = false
```

Comment: `namespaces=true` is the default

Comment: I believe it should be lowercase "false". I get an error "Could not parse 'pyproject.toml': Invalid value (at line X, column Y)" if it's capitalized.